# Why is UITextView scrolled down?

Tags: scroll, uitextview

I'a beginner to iOS and I'm testing the sizeToFit function to make a UITextField that changes it's height based on its text. When I run this code the "Hello World" string is scrolled down.

Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *testString2 = @"Hello World!";

    [testTextVIew setText:testString2];

    CGSize size = [testTextVIew sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(182.0f, MAXFLOAT)];

    [testTextVIew setFrame:CGRectMake(testTextVIew.frame.origin.x, testTextVIew.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height)];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Xcode and the problem was fixed. I hope Apple is aware of all these bugs and is working on them.